# Second parameter is not applied when using native query and H2

Tags: java, spring, csv, jpa, h2

I'm trying to load some csv files into H2 database with `CSVREAD()`

```
Query nativeQuery = entityManager.createNativeQuery("INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME SELECT NULL as ID, (SELECT (?1) FROM CSV_FILE_IMPORT WHERE ID=@csv_import) as IMPORT_ID, * FROM CSVREAD( (?2) );");
nativeQuery.setParameter(1, id);
nativeQuery.setParameter(2, pathToFile);

nativeQuery.executeUpdate();
```

If I use one parameter everything works fine, if I use the second one the query can't be prepared any more.

This occurs only if I'm using `CSVREAD()`. In a simple `SELECT` I can use more than one parameter.

What I've tried:

- using named parameters like `:id`
- changing the order of the two parameters
- using only `?` (without number)

Nothing has worked for me and now I have to use another table with all needed data as a helper, so I only need one parameter.

Comment: what is the actual error?

Comment: `Parameter "fileName" is not set; `